# How to run particular url on repayment of weekly plan in stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have created a weekly plan on stripe payment gateway. I have following code for subscribing a particular plan to the particular customer :

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
            "card" => $token,
            "plan" => $PlanID,
            "email" => $email
            )
        );
```

this code is running successfully but when this plan will be charged after a week then how can I get an update in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Stripe Webhooks to keep your database in sync with Stripe.

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

I think you need to listen for the `charge.succeeded` event.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types